# Obtain last 500 logged messages

Tags: java, email, slf4j, logback, tail

We are using SLF4J/Logback combination to perform our logging. One of the requirement we have is if anything fails, send an email to support/dev group with last 500 logged messages.

I was trying to go through the documentation, but haven't found anything relevant.

One of the approach, I can think is obtain the current log file name, read the file and send last 500 records. But I dont know how to get the current log file name. anyone knows how to? or any other better option to retrieve the log tail?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like Log4j's `SMTPAppender` has the features you require. You could look at its source code as model to guide your own implementation if Logback lacks a similar appender (which would be somewhat surprising).

Essentially, this email appender has a ring buffer of log events. When a triggering event occurs (by default, an event at ERROR level or worse), the buffer is flushed to an email and sent.

Comment: @Raahul - As I suspected, Logback's `SMTPAppender` has essentially the same features as Log4j's version. You shouldn't have to write any code; just configure the appender with the buffer size and trigger condition that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Appender that would cache the last 500 log messages. You may extend the [SMTPAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/access/net/SMTPAppender.html) to shoot the email by reading the contents from this cache.

start [here](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/core/Appender.html)